# При создании бота произошла ошибка Connection pool of Request object is smaller than optimal value (8)

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Если что использую на pycharm

```
from telegram import Bot
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler
from telegram.ext import Filters
from config import TG_TOKEN


def do_start(bot: Bot, update: Update):
    bot.send_message(
        chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
        text='hi',
    )


def do_echo(bot: Bot, update: Update):
    text = update.message.text
    bot.send_message(
        chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
        text=text,
    )


def main():
    bot = Bot(
        token=TG_TOKEN,
    )
    updater = Updater(
        bot=bot,
    )

    start_handler = CommandHandler('start', do_start)
    message_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text, do_echo)

    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(message_handler)

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Правильно ли установлены зависимости?

Возможно поможет следующее:

```
pip uninstall python-telegram-bot
pip install python-telegram-bot==11.1.0
```

Comment: если так то вылазит UserWarning: python-telegram-bot wasn't properly installed. Please refer to README.rst on how to properly install. warnings.warn("python-telegram-bot wasn't properly installed. Please refer to README.rst on "
Traceback (most recent call last):